# Overriden `Process.run` does not execute asynchronously

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Having subclassed `Process.run`

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

DELAY = 2

class NewProcess(mp.get_context().Process):
    def run(self) -> None:
        # add new kwarg to item[4] slot
        old_que = self._args[0]
        new_que = mp.SimpleQueue()
        while not old_que.empty():
            item = old_que.get()
            new_que.put(
                (
                    item[0],
                    item[1],
                    item[2], # Function
                    item[3], # Arguments
                    item[4]  # Keyword arguments
                    | {
                        "message": "Hello world!",
                    },
                )
            )
        # Recreate args
        self._args = new_que, *self._args[1:]
        # Continue as normal
        super().run()


def delay(*args, **kwargs):
    time.sleep(DELAY)
    return args, kwargs


if __name__ == "__main__":
    context = mp.get_context()
    context.Process = NewProcess
    with context.Pool(2) as pool:
        responses = []
        start = time.perf_counter()
        for _ in range(2):
            resp = pool.apply_async(
                func=delay,
                args=tuple(range(3)),
                kwds={},
            )

            responses.append(resp)
        for resp in responses:
            resp.wait()

        responses = [resp.get() for resp in  responses]
        total = time.perf_counter() - start

        assert total - DELAY < 1e-2, f"Expected to take circa {DELAY}s, took {total}s"

        assert responses == (
            expected := list(
                (
                    (0, 1, 2),
                    {
                        "message": "Hello world!"
                    }
                )
            )
        ), f"{responses=}!={expected}"
```

I would expect that `delay` function executes asynchronously taking circa `DELAY` time. However, it does not. Script fails with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vahvero/Desktop/tmp.py", line 54, in <module>
    assert total - DELAY < 1e-2, f"Expected to take circa {DELAY}s, took {total}s"
AssertionError: Expected to take circa 2s, took 4.003754430001209s
```

Why my changes to `run` cause linear rather than parallel processing?

Comment: See [this article on the XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). What is it that you *ultimately* need to do driving you to override this method? Maybe there is a better, alternate way,

Comment: I wish to know __why__ here. Not how to do X. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.run) actual behavior is not ultimately clear, but it does imply that subclassing should be possible with respect to `args`  and `kwargs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have what I believe to be 3 issues with your code, two minor and one major:

1. What you state should be the expected `responses` values is not correct, i.e. you should be expecting two (2) tuples in the returned list.
2. The time you expect the two tasks to run needs to be a bit more generous as on a slower machine the overhead of creating and initializing processes could very well be more than .01 secods.
3. Each pool process is creating its own new `SimpleQueue` instance. So instead of having a single queue instance with two items on it, we now have 2 queue instances each with two items on it for a total of 4 tasks to process. This is why it is taking twice as long as you think it should.

The following code does not create any new queue instances but instead modifies the items (tasks) on the queue if necessary. I ensure that the rewriting of the queue is performed only once. The code also prints out the results and timing:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
from functools import partial

DELAY = 2


class NewProcess(mp.get_context().Process):
    def __init__(self, rewritten, *args, **kwargs):
        self._rewritten = rewritten
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def run(self) -> None:
        que = self._args[0]
        # add new kwarg to item[4] slot
        with self._rewritten.get_lock():
            # has the queue been rewritten?
            if not self._rewritten.value:
                items = []
                while not que.empty():
                    item = que.get()
                    if not item[4]:
                        item = list(item)
                        item[4] = {"message": "Hello world!"}
                        item = tuple(item)
                    items.append(item)
                for item in items:
                    que.put(item)
                self._rewritten.value = 1
        super().run()

def create_new_process(rewritten, *args, **kwargs):
    return NewProcess(rewritten, *args, **kwargs)

def delay(*args, **kwargs):
    time.sleep(DELAY)
    return args, kwargs


if __name__ == "__main__":
    context = mp.get_context()
    rewritten = mp.Value('i', 0) # Queue has not yet been rewritten
    context.Process = partial(create_new_process, rewritten)
    with context.Pool(2) as pool:
        responses = []
        start = time.time()
        for _ in range(2):
            resp = pool.apply_async(
                func=delay,
                args=tuple(range(3)),
                kwds={},
            )

            responses.append(resp)
        """
        # This is unnecessary: # Booboo
        for resp in responses:
            resp.wait()
        """

        responses = [resp.get() for resp in  responses]
        total = time.time() - start
        print(responses)
        print(total)

        # Be a bit more time tolerant: # Booboo
        assert total < DELAY + .2, f"Expected to take circa {DELAY}s, took {total}s"

        # You are expecting 2 items returned:
        assert responses == (
            expected := [
                (
                    (0, 1, 2),
                    {
                        "message": "Hello world!"
                    }
                )
            ] * 2 # Note this line
        ), f"{responses=}!={expected}"
```

Prints:

```None
[((0, 1, 2), {'message': 'Hello world!'}), ((0, 1, 2), {'message': 'Hello world!'})]
2.1168272495269775
```

**Note**

The reason why I mentioned in my comment the XY problem is because I wanted to understand what your ultimate goal was and to determine whether there was a better, safer way of accomplishing this. Your goal seems to be to ensure that if no keyword arguments were passed to your worker function, then you would provide a default. If so, surely there is a cleaner, simpler, more efficient way. For example, we can use a *decorator* function:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
from functools import wraps

DELAY = 2


def provide_default_keywords(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if not kwargs:
            kwargs = {"message": "Hello world!"}
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@provide_default_keywords
def delay(*args, **kwargs):
    time.sleep(DELAY)
    return args, kwargs


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with mp.Pool(2) as pool:
        responses = []
        start = time.time()
        for _ in range(2):
            resp = pool.apply_async(
                func=delay,
                args=tuple(range(3)),
                kwds={},
            )

            responses.append(resp)

        responses = [resp.get() for resp in  responses]
        total = time.time() - start
        print(responses)
        print(total)

        # Be a bit more time tolerant: # Booboo
        assert total < DELAY + .2, f"Expected to take circa {DELAY}s, took {total}s"

        # You are expecting 2 items returned:
        assert responses == (
            expected := [
                (
                    (0, 1, 2),
                    {
                        "message": "Hello world!"
                    }
                )
            ] * 2 # Note this line
        ), f"{responses=}!={expected}"
```

**Update**

See my comment below concerning the race condition that renders your initial approach problematic. If you don't want to use a decorator, then better would be to override the `apply_async` method. In the following code I create a mixin class to do just that and it can be used with a multiprocessing pool or a multithreading pool:

```py
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool
import time

DELAY = 2

class Apply_Async_Mixin: # Can be used with multiprocessing or multithreading
    def apply_async(self, func, args=(), kwds={}, callback=None,
            error_callback=None):
        if not kwds:
            kwds = {"message": "Hello world!"}
        return super().apply_async(func,
                                   args=args,
                                   kwds=kwds,
                                   callback=callback,
                                   error_callback=error_callback)

# You must specify the mixin first:
class MyPool(Apply_Async_Mixin, Pool): # multiprocessing
    pass

def delay(*args, **kwargs):
    time.sleep(DELAY)
    return args, kwargs

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with MyPool(2) as pool:
        start = time.time()
        async_results = [
            pool.apply_async(
                func=delay,
                args=tuple(range(3)),
                kwds={},
            )
            for _ in range(2)
        ]
        responses = [async_result.get() for async_result in async_results]
        total = time.time() - start

        print(responses)
        print(total)

        # Be a bit more time tolerant: # Booboo
        assert total < DELAY + .2, f"Expected to take circa {DELAY}s, took {total}s"

        # You are expecting 2 items returned:
        assert responses == (
            expected := [
                (
                    (0, 1, 2),
                    {
                        "message": "Hello world!"
                    }
                )
            ] * 2 # Note this line
        ), f"{responses=}!={expected}"
```

Comment: Summa summarum: The creation of new `SimpleQueue` doubled the number of delay calls for two processes and led to 2x increase?

Comment: Yes. Each pool process was working of its own copy of a task queue so there were a total of 4 instances of `delay` having to be run but your pool size was only 2 and the 4 tasks could not all be run concurrently. By the way, I have also updated the answer to ensure that the queue is only rewritten once (by the first `NewProcess` instance that executes the `run` method). But you really should consider using the decorator I defined.

Comment: You are correct, if the keyword does not change. I would probably consider just doing away with `Pool` and just recreating the `Process` with the keywords. I don't think one can pass a new function to `Process` which leads the the recreation requirement. The code would not be that complex I think.

Comment: It works on my Windows but not on my Linux. It's a timing issue: When the `run` method code that rewrites the queue is executed, there is nothing yet on the queue. A race condition exists between the main process calling `apply_async` to place tasks on the queue and the pool creating the processes. In Windows, the calls to `apply_async` complete before  the queue rewrite code is entered but on my Linux the queue rewriting code is invoked before the main process adds tasks. If you put a call to `time.sleep(.1)` at the top of the rewriting code, it works. **You should abandon this approach!**

Comment: Yes I agree. Coding with `Process` inheritance feels like trying the hit a nut into a board which usually means one is attempting to do something intended by Python developers.

Comment: See my update to the answer that creates a pool subclass.